# getting rails started on windows 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I configure a rails simple_app ran this command

```
rails new simple_app -d mysql
```

now when I try to start rails server I get

```
 515 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_view/helpers/atom_feed_helper.rb
 516 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_view/helpers/cache_helper.rb
 517 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_view/helpers/controller_helper.rb
 518 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_view/helpers/csrf_helper.rb
 519 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_view/helpers/date_helper.rb
 520 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_view/helpers/debug_helper.rb
 521 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_view/helpers/javascript_helper.rb
 522 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/array/access.rb
 523 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_view/helpers/url_helper.rb
 524 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/string/filters.rb
 525 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_view/helpers/sanitize_helper.rb
 526 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_view/helpers/text_helper.rb
 527 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_view/helpers/form_tag_helper.rb
 528 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_view/helpers/tags.rb
 529 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_view/model_naming.rb
 530 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb
 531 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_view/helpers/form_options_helper.rb
 532 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/number_helper.rb
 533 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_view/helpers/number_helper.rb
 534 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_view/helpers/output_safety_helper.rb
 535 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/module/qualified_const.rb
 536 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/module.rb
 537 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_view/record_identifier.rb
 538 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_view/helpers/record_tag_helper.rb
 539 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_view/helpers/rendering_helper.rb
 540 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_view/helpers/translation_helper.rb
 541 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_view/helpers.rb
 542 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.0.1/lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb
 543 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/engine/configuration.rb
 544 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/application/configuration.rb
 545 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.0.1/lib/sprockets/railtie.rb
 546 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/all.rb
 547 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/string_inquirer.rb
 548 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.15/lib/mysql2/version.rb
 549 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.15/lib/mysql2/error.rb
```

I erased this multiple times and tried to do it again.

---

this seems to fix the segmentation fault problem

---

The libmysql.lib included in the MySQL Connector/C 64 bit is not compatible with the mingw64-gcc compiler.

You need to generate mingw64 compatible libmysql.lib file.

To generate libmysql.lib file, you need gendef.exe, which can obtain from mingw-w64 distribution

In the lib folder of the mysql connector, produce libmysql.lib with the following steps.

gendef.exe libmysql.dll

dlltool -v --dllname libmysql.dll --def libmysql.def --output-lib libmysql.lib

after gendef.exe run gem command: gem install mysql2 --no-rdoc --no-ri -- '--with-mysql-lib="C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\lib" --with-mysql-include="C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\include" '

it won't work with the command [--with-opt-dir] on windows (I did this on windows 7)

worked with the latest MySQL version

Source: https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/8591

Comment: With no actual error message?

Comment: This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information. the file starts with an message but the files continue on until its stops and the message is no longer viewable

Comment: http://s1.postimg.org/7qqg6e0ov/rails_mysql_error.png   here is the problem

Comment: How did you install everything? Did you use railsinstaller?

Comment: no rails installer ruby installer then downloaded everything using gem install I am running ruby 64-bit. I compile mysql2 with the c connector

Comment: That's probably the issue, try railsinstsller.

Comment: if I have ruby 64-bit do I compile the mysql2 to 64-bit or 32-bit or does it even matter

Comment: No idea; there's a reason railsinstaller exists--because getting all this stuff to work on Windows is a PITA. http://railsinstaller.org

Comment: does rails installer come with rails 4